# ngrok killing a tunnel from windows 7 command line

Tags: windows, ngrok

I'm trying to use ngrok to foward my app,  currently hosted on localhost:3602, to my development partner.

I've done this many times in the past successfully, simply by typing in

```
ngrok http 3602
```

I get back a url that he can conntect to. But now when I type that in I get the following error message:

> Tunnel session failed. Your account is limited to 1 simultaneous ngrok client session.
>   Active ngrok client sessions in region 'us':
>   - f21bd0dbe67928069054c733a5e11f88 (54.80.69.18)
>   ERR_NGROK_108

Obviously I must have an existing tunnel session running somewhere.

My problem is I have no idea where to find that existing tunnel session and how to terminate it. It does not exist as either a running application, process or service in the task manager, and I can find no syntax in the documentation for how to terminate a tunnel session. I've tried rebooting my machine to no effect, which tells me this is probably not a local problem, but rather something running on the ngrok site linked to my account, yet nothing I can find in my account settings indicates anything helpful.

Can anyone provide the necessary command to clear up this problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 27):

for window version:

```
tskill /A ngrok
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

**For Linux/Mac**

```
killall ngrok
```

This command is an Unix command. In Windows you can open the Task Manager and close all ngrok processes.

Comment: Thanks. I tried what you suggested. I got back: 'killall' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Answer (score 2):

This answer is not about killing tunnel, but about a possible solution to the described problem with ERR_NGROK_108.

https://dashboard.ngrok.com/get-started/setup
describes a simple plan for getting started with ngrok.

[image]

If you execute the second step you will have a file ngrok.yaml (In my case path was: `C:\Users\Mi\ .ngrok2\ngrok.yml`).

And after that executing `ngrok http 80` will provide the described error ERR_NGROK_108.

**Solution:**

- **Skip the second step**. Execute `ngrok http 80` without previous `ngrok authtoken`
- If you have already executed this step, **delete the file ngrok.yml**

This approach solved my problem with ERR_NGROK_108.

Comment: Thx! simply deleting ngrok.yml solved it for me, after 3 days of killing / searching SO / rebooting and no changes

Answer (score 2):

on your ngrok prompt just run this command

taskkill /f /im ngrok.exe

Answer (score 0):

It seems like *ngrok* got a (JavaScript) function for that:

```
const ngrok = require('ngrok');
ngrok().kill();
```

Comment: Is it Js or what?

Comment: @standalone yes, it is.

Answer (score 0):

If you are limited to one session — like I was. Then you may have created an account with `ngrok` and signed in with your machine. And it'll create a file:

```
C:\Users\<name>\.ngrok2\ngrok.yml
```

It uses this to limit your client, simply delete this file.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows(cmd):

```
taskkill /f /im ngrok.exe
```

[image]